# Move product backlog items to another teamwork board project

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm going to move PBIs(product backlog items) with its tasks to another teamwork board project, but I couldn't find an option to do this, it would be so helpful if anyone could help me.[image]

Comment: Please use correct terminology. "Teamwork board project" is not TFS terminology; it's a mixture of different things and can be interpreted in several different ways. Do you mean a team project? Do you mean a different team within a team project?

Comment: Thank you, I agree with that. I mean move to another team project. @DanielMann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the  Azure DevOps Server, you can [change the work item type or move work items to another project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops-2019#prerequisites) within a project collection, these features require that the data warehouse is disabled.

[Disable warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/admin/disable-data-warehouse?view=azure-devops-2019) steps:

Open Azure DevOps Server Administration Console->Reporting->Click the button Disable Reporting->Enter the server name to confirm.
[image]

Then you can see the button move to team project and change type… in the Drop-down list.

[image]